# returning a true or false method

Tags: java, class, methods, boolean

```
public class Book { 
String title; 
boolean borrowed; 
// Creates a new Book 
public Book(String bookTitle){ 
    bookTitle= "The Da Vinci Code";
} 
// Marks the book as rented 
public void borrowed() { 
    int borrowed= 1;
    // Implement this method 
} 
// Marks the book as not rented 
public void returned() { 
    int returned = 2;
    // Implement this method 
} 
// Returns true if the book is rented, false otherwise 
public boolean isBorrowed(int returned, int borrowed) { 
    if (borrowed < 2 )
    return true;
    else 
    return false;
    // Implement this method 
} 
// Returns the title of the book 
public String getTitle() { 
    String bookTitle= "The Da Vinci Code";
    return bookTitle;
    // Implement this method 
}

public static void main(String[] arguments){ 
    // Small test of the Book class
    int returned= 1;
    int borrowed= 2;
    Book example = new Book("The Da Vinci Code"); 
    System.out.println("Title (should be The Da Vinci Code): " +example.getTitle()); 
    System.out.println("Borrowed? (should be false): " + example.isBorrowed(returned, borrowed)); 
    example.borrowed(); 
    System.out.println("Borrowed? (should be true): " + example.isBorrowed(returned, borrowed)); // should be returning true but it not. It printing false
    example.returned(); 
    System.out.println("Borrowed? (should be false): " + example.isBorrowed(returned, borrowed)); 
}
```

I'm doing classes and method.I'm making a book class and it is almost working but I need to get the second print statement to print true but i'm get false. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: You don't seem to have any idea what you are doing. Go back to the drawing board. Go through the most basic tutorials, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Comment: Your local variables are blocking access to the class fields. Remove the "int" declarations.

Answer (score 0):

You are making a new int in void borrowed and its a different int than the one in the main method so make it an attribute to the class int borrowed don't declare it twice.

Answer (score -1):

You set the local variable `borrowed` to 2 in the `main()` method. You call `isBorrowed()` and pass it this variable. Then in `isBorrowed()` you say to return true if `borrowed` is less than 2. It is not so you return false.

Your `borrowed()` method needs to set the `borrowed` field in `Book` to true, not set a local variable.

You should learn the difference between *declaring* a variable and *assigning* a value to a variable